# Question regarding pulling out variables from integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Say you have: $u(x)=\int xy\mathrm d y = x \int y\mathrm d y$

Then you plug in y to u(.) using both original and simplified forms: $$u(y)=y\int y\mathrm d y\neq \int y^2\mathrm  dy$$

Which is correct? I'm guessing it's the one using the original form but I'm not sure...

P.S. This is the original problem (integral equation) that inspired the question (when you expand u(t)), from my textbook.

$$u(x) =\dfrac{5x}{6}+\dfrac 12\int_0^1 xt u(t)~\mathrm d t$$

Comment: $u(y)$ should be $u(y) = y \int t \ dt$ to avoid the use of one symbol $y$ to mean two different things.

Comment: I'm dealing with an integral equation which references itself and I think is in the correct form (I'm getting it from a textbook). Let me post the original problem.

Comment: @Randall : so just double checking you're sure about this? I've never dealt with this type of problem before.

Comment: I don't see how the integral equation you posted relates to the question you're asking.

Comment: $u(x)=\int xy\;dy$ does not make sense since the right hand side is a *family* of functions.

Comment: @Randall I was just saying that when you expand u(t) you get the same situation I was describing...

Comment: But you can't really "expand it" like that.  It is being integrated, and there is a $t$ attached to it.

Comment: @LouisPan what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $x$ is not being integrated so we can take it out. Also, definite integrals are constants. We can collect all the constants and call it $k$. We can integrate $t(kt)$ with respect to $t$ and finally solve for $k$.

\begin{align}
u(x) &= \left(\frac{5}{6} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 tu(t)\;dt\right)x \\
u(x) &= kx\\
\int_0^1 tu(t)\;dt &= \int_0^1 kt^2\;dt = \frac{k}{3}\\
kx &= \left(\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{k}{3}\right)x\\
k&= \frac{5}{6}+\frac{k}{6}
\end{align}

Solving the linear equation we obtain $k = 1$, so $u(x) = x$.